# R Match value in data.frame with a variable

Tags: r, compare

I am trying to search through a data.frame and get a value in the same row, a few columns away. I have input the file but what remains is to search for the the variable. In that, I do not know how to begin. In the small sample of the table, that I have included below, I need to search through and find a value (which is stored as a variable) in id (which will be unique) and return that value to a new variable, which could be used in a graph title.

```
id,cov
2A,50
2b,3
8f,12
```

I imagine I might have to use something like this:

```
 comparison <- compare(s,search,allowAll=TRUE)
```

but I was hoping someone had some suggestions or guidance on the matter so as to limit my blundering

```
#Got the cov column
m<-data.frame(MNS=c(mns$cov))
head(m)
    MNS
1 50
2 3
3 12
#Got the id column
s<-data.frame(SPL=c(mns$id))
#The value that I would like to search for
search<-'2b'
head(search)
[1] "2b"
#My attempt to find it
see<-mns[mns$id=='search',]
head(see)
 [1] sample_id                              
 [2] meanCov                                            
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... does `mns[msn$id=='2b',]` not do what you want?

Comment: No, sorry for being unclear. Search actually is a variable that changes based on a separate file and using msn[msn$id=='search',] just gives the column names, not the value of the column that I need.

Comment: It does not 'give' the column names. It 'prints' the column names with the row values below them. What you see at the console is not the actual object returned.

Comment: see DWin's comment below, but you don't want to quote search.  use `mns[mns$id == search,]` or `mns[mns$id %in% search,]`.  your code with quoted search just returned a `data.frame` with 0 rows because it was looking for the word 'search'

Comment: So you want to get the cov value that correponds to that id value, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are after something like this

```
mns[msn$id == "2b", "cov"]
```

## Updated with the new comments

```
msn[msn$id == search, "cov"]
```

or

```
msn[msn$id %in% search, "cov]
```

Comment: Has an advantage over a match based method that all matches will be returned. Could also use '%in%' instead of "==" and get more generality.

Comment: What is it that %in% does? Is is an approximate match?

Comment: It's like match, but it returns a logical vector.

Comment: `%in%` is more like `sapply( x, "==", val)` than it is like `match`. `match` only returns the first matched position and ignores later ones.